# $a,b,c$ are distinct real number

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

$a,b,c$ are distinct real number such that $a^3=3(b^2+c^2)-25$, $b^3=3(c^2+a^2)-25$, $c^3=3(a^2+b^2)-25$. Find the numerical value of $abc$

Comment: But $a,b,c$ are distinct

Comment: @EwanDelanoy-But they are distinct...

Comment: Hint subtract eqn1-eqn2,eqn1-eqn3,eqn2-eqn3. You get as Ewan said $a=b=c$. I have done it then find the values.

Comment: No you get $a^2+ab+b^2=3(a+b)$ and similar for the other two.

Comment: @cr001: Did you get your sign correct?

Comment: @user21820 You are right, it should be $a^2+ab+b^2=3(-a-b)$ and so on then, which means all three numbers are less than zero.

Comment: @cr001 Applying the method $eqn1-eqn2,eqn1-eqn3,eqn2-eqn3$ to the newly found equations, you obtain $a+b+c=-3$.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Actually after finishing the answer I just realized $a+b<0,b+c<0,c+a<0$ does not imply $a<0,b<0,c<0$, sorry for the mistake above.

Answer (score 3):

Subtracting the equation will give you $a^2+ab+b^2=3(-a-b)$ and similar for the other two. Subtracting again will give you $(a+b+c)(b-c)=-3(b-c)\implies a+b+c=-3$.

Now add the three equations up we get $2a^2+2b^2+2c^2+ab+bc+ca=3(-2a-2b-2c)$ so $2(a+b+c)^2-3ab-3bc-3ca=-6(a+b+c)\implies ab+bc+ca=0$

Hence $a^2+b^2+c^2=9$

Now add the original three equations up you get $a^3+b^3+c^3=6\cdot9-75=-21$

Also since $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$

You get $-21-3abc=(-3)(9)$

Hence $abc=2$